# Hyperperception model psychology?

Tags: social-psychology, cyberpsychology

Is hyperperception model related to Psychology or communication studies? I have read articles like (Carpenter & Spottswood, 2021) but still wonder which Psychology is it related to or is it just a communication theory?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Can you please provide a full citation for Carpenter & Spottswood (2021)? That could be anything and it would make finding it easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to:

Carpenter, C. J., & Spottswood, E. L. (2021). The Hyperperception Model: When Your Partner's New Friends Inspire Jealousy and Failing to Use Social Distancing. *Cyberpsychology, Behavior, and Social Networking, 24*(7), 439-443. https://doi.org/10.1089/cyber.2020.0492

The article details give you a clue. For one, you have tagged the question correctly as a Social Psychology question, but it also crosses into Behavioural Psychology and a recently new branch of psychology called Cyberpsychology.

> Cyberpsychology is a scientific inter-disciplinary domain that focuses on the psychological phenomena which emerge as a result of the human interaction with digital technology, particularly the Internet — Source: British Psychological Society (BPS, n.d.)

### References

BPS (n.d.). *Cyberpsychology Section* https://www.bps.org.uk/member-microsites/cyberpsychology-section